# Retrofit : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.retrofitd.rest.LoginModel$Data.getFirstName()'

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to implement Retrofit in my app.
getting below error :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.retrofitd.rest.LoginModel$Data.getFirstName()' on a null object reference
                                                                 at com.retrofitd.MainActivity$1$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:46)
                                                                 at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
```

My **API CLIENT** class is as below  :

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://999.99.999.99/~test/master/api/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**API INTERFACE** is as below :

```
public interface ApiInterface {//    gym/gymdetail
    @POST("webservice/login")
    Call<LoginModel> getGymDetails(@Query("username") String userId,@Query("password")String strGymId);
}
```

and below **`MainActivity.java`**, using like this :

```
ApiInterface apiService =
                    ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

            Call<LoginModel> call = apiService.getGymDetails("sssss", "123456");
            call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LoginModel> call, Response<LoginModel> response) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + response.body().getData().getFirstName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<LoginModel> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

Also set Internet permission in manifest.
What might be the issue ? Thanks.

**EDIT**
Let me add my model class. My model class for login is as below.
Please, check it out. 
my model class :

```
public class LoginModel {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Integer status;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private Data data;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;

public Integer getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public class Data {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    @Expose
    private String first_name;
    @SerializedName("last_name")
    @Expose
    private String last_name;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("password")
    @Expose
    private String password;
    @SerializedName("photo")
    @Expose
    private String photo;
    @SerializedName("birthdate")
    @Expose
    private String birthdate;
    @SerializedName("gender")
    @Expose
    private String gender;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLastName(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getBirthdate() {
        return birthdate;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(String birthdate) {
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: show the responce json data

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi Its not duplicate. remove your flag pls.

Comment: What is the code of MainActivity.java, line 46?

Comment: @vinay i am getting "Failure" in response.body()

Comment: response.body().getData() is returning null i think

Comment: and error when response.body().getData().getFirstName()

Comment: you need to post your logcat of error you are getting.

Comment: @chandanicpatel ya,why ? Its giving me Failure

Comment: response.body() or response.body().getData() returns null

Comment: on failure executing means u are not sending response properly

Comment: this is probably because you are using a `POST` request and sending data as `queryparams`

Comment: there is an issue in either url or request you are sending

Comment: r u sure this is valid url ?? http://999.99.999.99/~test/master/api/

Comment: am using my url, it's just due to not share with all. response is proper in postman. :)

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez You may be right. In demo it was GET and I changed to POST. I think i have to deal differently with the POST. let me try. thanks.

Comment: OHH MY GOD, the issue was : NOTHING. Actually, My mobile data was turned off. just on it. and getting success instead of onFailure() method called. Sry for not checking internet connection before calling api. ;)

Comment: But, yes changed to POST and added  :@FormUrlEncoded and :@Field instead of :@Query. 
Thanks to But, yes changed to POST and added  :@FormUrlEncoded and :@Field instead of :@Query. 
Thanks to  @M.Waqas Pervez

Answer (score 0):

use `Postman` to check the response first, if it works properly then you have build POJO based on JSON rawdata using JSON schema to POJO. while sending request you have to pass that POJO class in it your problem is going to solve.

Comment: {
    "status": 1,
    "data": {
        "id": "551",
        "first_name": "Ssss",
        "last_name": "Sdsd",
        "email": "jaiminmoditest@jdmail.com",
        "username": "sssss",
        "password": "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e",
        "photo": "",
        "birthdate": "1963-02-13",
        "gender": ""
    },
    "message": "Successful Login"
}

Comment: then use this raw jsondata to build pojo class using json schema to pojo website rest u can find answers anywhere

Comment: in response do you getting first name in jsondata

Comment: since I was posting I changed my lines :  @POST("webservice/login")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<LoginModel> getGymDetails(@Field("username") String userId, @Field("password")String strGymId); But, getting Failure.

Comment: OHH MY GOD, the issue was : NOTHING. Actually, My mobile data was turned off. just on it. and getting success instead of onFailure() method called. Sry for not checking internet connection before calling api. ;)

Comment: for that first of all you have to check for internet connection programatically if it was not connected you have to show any toast message

Comment: ya Vinay, i know. :)

Answer (score 0):

create a jsonobject like this and post it in body

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("username","Ssss");
        jsonObject.put("password","Sdsd");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and change api interface call like this

```
Call<LoginModel> call = apiService.getGymDetails(jsonObject);
```

change interface like this

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@POST("webservice/login")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
Call<LoginModel> getGymDetails(@Body JSONObject jsonObject);
}
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1)

Comment: @jaimin is your backend configured with get/post?

Comment: ya, its configured post

Comment: try adding `@Headers` in `ApiInterface `  see updated answer

Comment: getting failure.

Comment: OHH MY GOD, the issue was : NOTHING. Actually, My mobile data was turned off. just on it. and getting success instead of onFailure() method called. Sry for not checking internet connection before calling api. ;)

Answer (score 0):

there can be many reasons for that .

1) your model class that you defined is is not matching the json coming from request

2) you are using wrong method eg post or get ?

but i see there can be a problem in your model class post it here so that it can be looked on to ?

Comment: Posted my model.

Comment: OHH MY GOD, the issue was : NOTHING. Actually, My mobile data was turned off. just on it. and getting success instead of onFailure() method called. Sry for not checking internet connection before calling api. ;)